# AWK script to print line with the largest number of fields

Tags: linux, unix, awk, gawk

The script below displays the largest number of fields in twister.txt.

```
  awk '{if (NF > max) max = NF} END{print max}' twister.txt
```

My question is, How do you display the line itself, which has the largest number of fields in twister.txt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
awk '{if (NF > max) {max = NF; line=$0}} END{print line}' twister.txt
```

Comment: it works!! why do you initilize the line to $0? How do you interpret this?

Comment: @anansharm `$0` is the current line. So when you find that you have to update `max`, you simply also update the variable `line` to the current line. Then at the end, the value of `line` is equal to the line where the maximum number of fields where found..